# Does a 2nd level Ancient Guardian druid have Woodland Stride?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, druid, archetype

So a [druid](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid) gets woodland stride at 2nd level.

At 3rd level the archetype [ancient guardian](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/archetypes/paizo-druid-archetypes/ancient-guardian-druid-archetype/) replaces it. I assume its 3rd level because it also affects trackless step.

So while I am a second level druid, do I have woodland stride?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a creature take its first level of level of druid, the creature must *also* take the druid archetype ancient guardian if it wants that archetype because that archetype alters a level 1 druid class feature (q.v. [Retraining](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/more-character-options/retraining/) on Archetype). Then, as [Archetypes](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/class-archetypes/) says, "Each alternate class feature presented in an archetype replaces a specific class feature from its parent class."

Thus, when the creature adopts the ancient guardian archetype, *all* of the archetype's class features cascade to alter the original druid class features, replacing the original class features *all at once* with the adopted archetype's class features. (A player might want to rewrite and make appropriate changes to the basic druid class features table so he can plot his character's advancement; the ancient guardian archetype alters *a lot* of druid stuff!)

So, unless the special ability trackless step is acquired through another means, a pure ancient guardian druid won't ever have the special ability trackless step from being a druid.

Comment: I was mostly wondering if the way it was presented meant you had access to woodland stride for a single level

Comment: @Fering The general rule is supposed to be sufficient, but, for clarity, I agree that archetypes should've had standardized language similar to—right above the special ability ancient ways—the extraordinary ability patience of nature ("An ancient guardian does not gain wild empathy at 1st level"). That would force all the archetype designers to refer to the original table to make sure they're making the correct changes at the correct levels, too.

Comment: If I cant take feats for class abilities I havent acquired yet, then when its worded poorly I shouldnt lose class abilities until I reach the level it says, lol

Comment: @Fering Better watch it with that attitude—that sounds like a good way to be held in contempt of [Gamer Court](http://www.kodtweb.com/2012/03/08/gamer-court-cont-3/).

Comment: @Fering that would mean that archetypes could only be balanced against the abilities they replace. Some archetypes actually replace several abilities in order to gain one (considered stronger) ability.

Comment: @ShadowKras When they do the language is usually better however. HeyIcanChan makes that point in that they should be using standardized language.